# Alpha lists for html emails?

Tags: html, list, email, alphabet

I'm doing a html email where I need to do a numeric list which also has an indented letter list. e.g. 
     1. Example
          a. sub example
     2. Example

etc

I'm looking for something which will work across various email clients and will have the correct indentation I'm after which you get from html lists. I know you can do this by making various tables but I want a tidier way.

Here's an example of the type of code I'm looking for incase you need a bit more info to help:

```
 <ol>
      <li>Example</li>
      <ol>
           // Alphabet list item valid in html emails
      </ol>
      <li>Example</li>
 </ol>
```

Can I just use:

```
 <li type="a">sub example</li>
```

or is this invalid code for some email clients?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think if you put the type="a" on the indented OL it will work,

Comment: The `type="a"` attribute can be used on both `li` and `ol` elements; it is of course more compact to put it in `ol` only. Whether this is OK to all email clients is difficult to say; I would expect it to be, since this is a very old and easily implementable HTML feature.